# Call Log vs Call Logs. Which is correct?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen both the versions being used. Are both of these correct?

Comment: One would probably be better than the other in a given context.

Comment: Could you please share an example in context to above question. Which one should be used, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, based on the context.

I'll try for a basic example here:

> "Each user submits a **Call Log** at the end of the day."
>
> "The admins reviews all **Call Logs** which have been submitted by
>   each user."

I hope this provides some clarity for you :)